# Linking of atoms in a molecule of finitely many atoms

Tags: combinatorics

Let $[n]=\{1,\ldots, n\}$ (the $n$ "atoms" in the molecule) and let $A\subseteq [n]\times [n]$ be a symmetric relation, i.e., if $(p,q)\in A$ then $(q,p)\in A$. Let $H_k=\{(p,q)\in A:q=k\}$. $A$ satisfy the property that $\text{card}(A\cap H_i)=\text{card}(A\cap H_j)$ for all $i,j\in[n]$. My question is: is it possible for the above situation to happen for all pairs of positive integers $(n,k)$ where $k\leq n$ or is it just possible for some particular $(n,k)$? Given a fixed value of $k$, what are the possible values of $n$?

I come up with this myself and could not get a solution. Is there any reference to this?

Comment: What is $k$? Is it *the* value of $\text{card}(A\cap H_i)$ (the one that does not depend on $i$)? If that is the case, the fact that you used letter $k$ in the sentence previous to that is also a bit confusing. (Did you really want to ask this: "In a molecule of $n$ atoms, every atom bonds to exactly $k$ other atoms. Is it possible for the above situation to happen etc. etc."?) Also, do you assume anything about bonds of atoms "to themselves" (i.e. for which $p$ does $(p,p)\in A$)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the concept you're looking for is a [regular graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph). A $k$-regular graph is a graph where every vertex (atom) has degree $k$ (is connected to exactly $k$ other atoms).

From that Wikipedia article we have the following fact, which answers your question:

> It is well known that the necessary and sufficient conditions for a $k$ regular graph of order $n$ to exist are that $n\geq k+1$ and that $nk$ is even.